# How to get item in a JList and remove it?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcheckbox, defaultlistmodel

I am unable to remove an item from `JList`. The following code has been put on the `JButton`.

```
 DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list1.getModel();

     int selectedIndex = list1.getSelectedIndex();
     if (selectedIndex != -1) 
     {
     model.remove(selectedIndex);
     }
```

Comment: there is no relation between your question title and question content ?

Comment: What is the problem you are getting? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @che The item in the Jlist is not getting Removed

Comment: Yeah code looks good. See if you have bind this JButton to actionListener.

Comment: @user1961285 Okay. Post the _JButton Action_ code that is calling the _removeMethod._

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work

```
JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove Selected Element");
removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int selectedIndex = list1.getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex != -1) {
            model.remove(selectedIndex);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nothing selected");
        }
    }
});
```